# Sending request on load of a popup.html to content script receives nothing in this case

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My Requirement is whenever I click on the Extension Icon that should send a Request to content script and that should send reply with required properties. I am able to send the request. And when I check console Content script is recieving the request and processing it.But At popup side I could not receive anything.
Here is the request handler in Content script

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function ListeningMethod(request, sender, callback)
{
    switch(request.action)
    {
        case "QuestionProperties":
            sendResponse({attributes: {"h":"s","r":"t"} });
        break;
    }
});
```

And on popup.html I am sending the request like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
            chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {action: "QuestionProperties"}, function(response){
                alert('received something'); // Even this is not alerting
                                    var data = JSON.parse(response.attributes);
                alert(JSON.stringify(data)); // Here also I could not recieve anything.  At Contentscript side I have checked the response that is being sent. I am able to see the data. But at Popup side I am unable to recieve it. Please help me on this. 
            });
        });
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `content_script` isn't calling the correct method to send the response. Your listener function is naming it `callback` but then trying to use `sendRequest`. You should also either remove the function name or define it outside of the addListener for clarity.

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, callback)
{
    switch(request.action)
    {
        case "QuestionProperties":
            callback({attributes: {"h":"s","r":"t"} });
        break;
    }
});
```